# How do I write tests for custom classes that primarily use ConnectApi?

Tags: chatter, unit-test, connect-api

I have implemented a VF page that displays a Chatter Group feed using the example classes provided in the [Salesforce Cookbook](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/cookbookRecipeSource?id=a1V30000000CS0jEAG). I have implemented all of these classes (with some tweaks and added functionality) except for the last 2 (FeedBodyParser and FeedItemPoster) as they were not needed for this project.

This page renders and works without errors and is included within another VF page. I have also extended the DemoController to add some functionality using 's. I have written tests for the getters and setters of all of the class variables for my controller extension and they pass. However, I am having extreme difficulty with testing any of the methods that rely on ConnectApi classes in each of the classes I have implemented from the Cookbook since most of them rely on having an existing ChatterFeed to work with and because I'm using Chatter with Apex, I do not have access to organizational data.

I have tried to implement a test class following the example in the Salesforce doc: [Testing ConnectApi Classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=connectAPI_TestingApex.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/connectAPI_TestingApex.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), but I keep getting an error when trying to call my Controller methods after using the setTestGetFeedItemsFromFeed() method that states that my controller method does not exist or has an incorrect signature.

I need to be able to create a feed and test against it for the FeedItemInfo, CommentInfo, etc. classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am nowhere near the 75% code coverage required for this project without being able to create these tests.

Here's a look at my Code:
Starting with my Controller(tweaked from DemoController)

```
global class CanNewsChatterFeedController {
    // get first page of news feed
    global ConnectApi.FeedItemPage getNewsFeed() {
        return ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, '0F9d00000000fJc');
    }

    // build list of wrapped feed items for display in VisualForce
    global List<FeedItemInfo> getNewsFeedForDisplay() {
        ConnectApi.FeedItemPage feed = getNewsFeed();      
        List<FeedItemInfo> result = new List<FeedItemInfo>();
        for (ConnectApi.FeedItem item : feed.items) {
            result.add(new FeedItemInfo(item));
        }

        return result;
    }

    global PageReference refreshFeed(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

My controller extension:

```
public with sharing class CanNewsChatterFeedExtension {
    //declare class variables
    public String feedItemId; 
    public String likeId;  
    public String commentToAdd; 
    public Integer pollChoicePosition; 

    // Constructor. Needed to use as an extension.
    public CanNewsChatterFeedExtension(CanNewsChatterFeedController custController) {}

    //call via javascript and actionFunction. Class variables feedItemId and commentToAdd are set by passing params via actionFunction
    public void addCommentToFeedItem(){
        try{
            FeedComment fcomment = new FeedComment();
            fcomment.FeedItemId = feedItemId; 
            fcomment.CommentBody = commentToAdd; 
            insert fcomment;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //call via javascript and actionFunction. Class variable feedItemId is set by passing params via actionFunction
    public void addLikeToFeedItem(){
        try{
            ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.likeFeedItem(null, this.feedItemId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //call via javascript and actionFunction. Class variable likeId is set by passing params via actionFunction
    public void removeLikeFromFeedItem(){
        try{
            ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.deleteLike(null, this.likeId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //call via javascript and actionFunction. Class variables feedItemId and pollChoicePosition are set by passing params via actionFunction
    public void addVoteToFeedItemPoll(){
        try{
            ConnectApi.FeedPoll thePoll = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedPoll(null, this.feedItemId);
            String pollChoiceId = thePoll.choices[this.pollChoicePosition-1].id;
            ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.voteOnFeedPoll(null, this.feedItemId, pollChoiceId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //begin getters
    public String getFeedItemId(){
        return this.feedItemId;    
    }
    public String getLikeId(){
        return this.likeId;    
    }
    public String getCommentToAdd(){
        return this.commentToAdd;    
    }
    public Integer getPollChoicePosition(){
        return this.pollChoicePosition;    
    }
    //begin setters
    public void setFeedItemId(String theId){
        this.feedItemId = theId;
    }
    public void setLikeId(String theId){
        this.likeId = theId;
    }
    public void setCommentToAdd(String theComment){
        this.commentToAdd = theComment;
    }
    public void setPollChoicePosition(Integer thePosition){
        this.pollChoicePosition = thePosition;
    }
}
```

My Controller Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class CanNewsChatterFeedTest{
    @isTest
    static void chatterFeedTest(){
        ConnectApi.FeedItemPage testPage = new ConnectApi.FeedItemPage();
        ConnectApi.FeedItem feedItem = new ConnectApi.FeedItem();
        ConnectApi.Comment comment = new ConnectApi.Comment();

        List<ConnectApi.FeedItem> testItemList = new List<ConnectApi.FeedItem>();
        testItemList.add(feedItem);
        testPage.items = testItemList;

        ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.setTestGetFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me', testPage);

        Test.startTest();
        System.assert(CanNewsChatterFeedController.getNewsFeed() instanceof ConnectApi.FeedItemPage);
        //keep getting error here that states:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: CanNewsChatterFeedController.getNewsfeed()
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

My Controller extension Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class CanNewsChatterFeedExtensionTest{
    @isTest
    static void canNewsChatterFeedExtensionTest(){
        //Instantiate and construct the controller class.   
        CanNewsChatterFeedExtension controller = new CanNewsChatterFeedExtension(new CanNewsChatterFeedController()); 

        //set class variables and assert that the getters return the expected values
        controller.setFeedItemId('theFeedItemId');
        System.assertEquals('theFeedItemId', controller.getFeedItemId());

        controller.setLikeId('theLikeId');
        System.assertEquals('theLikeId', controller.getLikeId());

        controller.setCommentToAdd('Test comment.');
        System.assertEquals('Test comment.', controller.getCommentToAdd());

        controller.setPollChoicePosition(1);
        System.assertEquals(1, controller.getPollChoicePosition());

       //setter and getter test work great, but how to test other methods called by apex:actionFunction?
    }
}
```

First attempt at the CommentInfo Test class:

```
@isTest
public class CommentInfoTest{
    @isTest
    static void commentInfoTest(){
        //instantiate and construct a ConnectApi.Comment object
        ConnectApi.Comment inComment = new ConnectApi.Comment();

        //instantiate and construct a CommentInfo object
        CommentInfo theCommentInfo = new CommentInfo(inComment);
        //set class variables and assert that the getters return the expected values
        //Somehow need to figure out how to instantiate a feed to get comments from for testing this
    }
}
```

I believe my problems stem from the fact that I need to simulate organization data for my tests of these classes, but the error I'm getting after trying to use the  setTestGetFeedItemsFromFeed() method is preventing me from building the data I need.

Comment: Not sure why my Test Class code broke like that when I posted, but if anyone knows, please let me know for future posts.

Comment: After copy-pasting your code, highlight the entire section of code and press Ctrl-K. This will indent the code correctly so that it doesn't break. You can fix it by editing your post.

Comment: I went ahead and edited your post, but essentially SFSE uses 4 spaces to indicate a line of code. The beginning and ending of all of your classes weren't indented the 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks @JesseAltman. Any suggestions on a solution for my issue

Comment: Anyone? No suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter values need to match exactly. Because your controller is calling

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, '0F9d00000000fJc');
```

you need to call

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.setTestGetFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, '0F9d00000000fJc', testPage);
```

in your test to register the test data, instead of

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.setTestGetFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me', testPage);
```

Comment: Thanks @alouie! That worked like a charm. Sorry it took so long to accept your answer. I was on vacation.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling CanNewsChatterFeedController.getNewsFeed() from the test class statically, but it's not defined as a static method. Try using

```
global static ConnectApi.FeedItemPage getNewsFeed() {
    ...
}
```

I did this in my dev org and it fixed the compiler error.

Comment: Thanks @alouie. I tried that, but then when I run the test, I get a different error that states: 
Error Message System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: No matching test result found for ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(String communityId, ConnectApi.FeedType feedType, String subjectId).

Before calling this, call ChatterFeeds.setTestGetFeedItemsFromFeed(String communityId, ConnectApi.FeedType feedType, String subjectId, ConnectApi.FeedItemPage result) to set the expected test result.

Comment: I get the above mentioned error even though I clearly call the setTestGetFeedItemsFromFeed() method directly before the Test.startTest() call. Could this be because I'm in a developer org and not a sandbox?

Comment: The problem is that the parameter values need to match exactly. I'll add another answer below, because I don't think I can format things the way I want in a comment.